# Textbook Taylor's Theorem Proof: Integration by Parts Notation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

My textbook begins its proof of Taylor's theorem as follows:

> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$$
>
> Next, we write $d \tau = -d(x_0 + h - \tau)$ and integrate by parts$^1$ to give
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau) \ d\tau$$
>
> $^1$ Recall that integration by parts (the product rule for the derivative read backward) reads as
>
> $$\int_a^b u \ dv = uv|^b_a - \int_a^b v \ du$$
>
> Here we choose $u = f'(\tau)$ and $v = x_0 + h - \tau$.

If we compare

$$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$$

and

$$\int_a^b u \ dv = uv|^b_a - \int_a^b v \ du,$$

and we select $u = f'(\tau)$, then, notationally, we must have that $v = \tau$. But the author set $v = x_0 + h - \tau$, which makes no sense when we logically compare the mathematical statements?

It seems to me like the author has confused themselves and/or just misused notation?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please clarify this.

Comment: ... "which implies $\tau = \pm(x_0 + h - \tau)$" is not true. How did you get $\pm$? Note that $d\tau=d(\tau+\text{const})$, and $x_0$, $h$ are constants w.r.t. $\tau$.

Comment: @A.Γ. You're right, my apologies. I seem to have completely confused myself somehow.

Comment: Oh, you do not have to apologize, you haven't done anything bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what he is really doing here is changing variables. A more proper way to do this would be to let $s = -(x_0+h-\tau)$, then $ds = d\tau$. Then change the integral to an integral over $s$. Essentially this equates the first integral with an integral over different bounds (bounds on $s$).

Your statement  "$d\tau=−d(x_0+h−\tau)$, which implies $\tau=\pm(x_0+h−\tau)$. So either $x_0=h=0$..." is not true. $d\tau=−d(x_0+h−\tau)$ implies that $\tau=-(x_0+h−\tau)+c$, where $c$ is an some constant, which we can set $c$ to $x_0+h$ to alleviate this issue. Notice that this is equivalent to defining $s$ as above and stating the fact that $\tau = s + x_0+h$, which is true from our construction.

Comment: Yes, I confused myself somehow with the latter part. Thank you for the clarification. So, with regards to the former issue, it does seem to be a misuse of notation?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a misuse of notation. He decided to skip a step or two in his presentation, but the way he presents it makes the integration by parts a lot clearer given that he skipped the explicit change of variables

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $d\tau=-d(x_0+h-\tau)$ does not imply that $\tau=-(x_0+h-\tau)$: two functions with the same derivatives on an interval differ by a constant, which here is $-(x_0+h)$.

Comment: You're right, I completely confused myself somehow. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @ThePointer: You're welcome!